# retrieving data from sql server using python pandas

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dataframe, merge

I have a time series of data stored in sql server database with the same schema. What I need to do is to read in the data between two specified dates. Right now I'm doing this: use pandas to query (read_sql_query) the database for each time period and then merge the data frame for each time period. I found this to be very inefficient, is there a better way to achieve this goal? In addition, from what I read, merging on index should be faster than merging on columns. However, I found the opposite from my test. Does anybody have any idea why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need help writing a single SQL Query to retrieve all the ranges, perhaps using [UNION ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql)?

Comment: If you add your table schema, some test data and your desired result you will get more relevant help.